# MySQL creating simple trigger issue (noob in MySQL)

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need to create a simple trigger:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `create_stock_articulo` AFTER INSERT ON `almacen_tb_articulos`
 FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM 'almacen_tb_almacenes';
        DECLARE id INT;
        OPEN cur;
        REPEAT
        FETCH cur INTO id;
             INSERT INTO 'almacen_tb_stock' VALUES (id,NEW.id);
        UNTIL done END REPEAT;
        CLOSE cur;
    END;//
```

This trigger is supposed to add rows on the table 'almacen_tb_stock' when a row is inserted in 'almacen_tb_articulos'. Each added row must contain 'almacen_tb_almacenes.id' and the new 'almacen_tb_articulos.id'.

When I try to create this trigger I get this error:

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''almacen_tb_almacenes'; DECLARE id INT; OPEN cur; REPEAT FETCH cur I' at line 4**

I can't see where the error is.

The table definitions are these:

almacen_tb_articulos:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `almacen_tb_articulos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `codigo` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  ... more irrelevant fields,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_familia` (`id_familia`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=43
```

almacen_tb_almacenes:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `almacen_tb_almacenes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `almacen` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `bloqueado` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

almacen_tb_stock:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `almacen_tb_stock` (
  `id_almacen` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_articulo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cantidad` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_almacen`,`id_articulo`),
  KEY `id_almacen` (`id_almacen`),
  KEY `id_articulo` (`id_articulo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: `SELECT id FROM 'almacen_tb_almacenes'` or `SELECT id FROM almacen_tb_almacenes`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several problems with your code:

1) The table name is enclosed in single quotes, 'almacen_tb_almacenes', which mean that it should be interpreted as a string literal. Instead enclose it with like so:  `almacen_tb_almacenes`. Or don't bother, because it can stand without the quotes.

2) Your code is missing a couple of declarations related to the cursor:

```
declare done int default false;
declare continue handler for not found set done = true;
```

3) Your loop structure is not quite right. Try this instead:

```
open cur;
read_loop: loop
    fetch cur into id;
    if done then
        leave read_loop;
    end if;
    insert into almacen_tb_stock VALUES (id,NEW.id);
end loop;
close cur;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, on Monday I'll test it but it looks pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a particular reason for using a cursor you can just use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM` syntax which will greatly simplify your code

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER create_stock_articulo
AFTER INSERT ON almacen_tb_articulos
FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO almacen_tb_stock (id_almacen, id_articulo) -- you have to add candidad here
  SELECT id, NEW.id -- and a value for candidas too
    FROM almacen_tb_almacenes;
```

Note: *In your `almacen_tb_stock` table you have a third `NOT NULL` column `cantidad` for which you have to provide a value in your insert statement, or define `DEFAULT` value in your schema.*